# How can I test browser back-button behavior using jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, enzyme, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom v4 and I simply want to test the behavior of the native browser back button (e.g. chrome). I'm not using `props.history.push` to navigate to a previous page or the `goBack()` method. Any thoughts on how I can test this behavior using jest and enzyme?

Comment: If we havent written any code for programattically taking the page to prev route, why are we writing unit test case for them at first place?

Comment: I wrote code that should be invoked after a native back button event and I want to write a test to mock that.

Comment: In my opinion, you cannot mock it as its like mocking an action to an application (browser) which is not in scope of your application (your react application). Please correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: Valid point. It's outside the scope. Thanks man!

Comment: You should provide the code you want to test